# How to use Internal Clock of PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mikroc

How to use the PIC micro controller's internal clock without using an external crystal?
Why most people prefer external crystals? Better if somebody can give a comparison

Thanks

Comment: Typically I only use a crystal if a part of the system requires it, say communication (CANBUS, etc..). It's a simple matter of configuration to enable the internal oscillator. Also http://electronics.stackexchange.com may be a better place for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this but only because it will get a better audience on the sister site http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

externals are more accurate, you can sometimes calibrate internal clocks on a per chip or per board basis, but they are going to be more sensitive to temperate change, etc.  Cost is another big factor if you are paying a buck or less for the microcontroller and have to double that or more to add the crystal that can affect the product price, margins, etc.  If this is for hobby stuff, using an external gives you better accuracy and no tuning, more happiness.